# Web API unable to serialize simple object due to SQL ServerVersion error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a fairly simply start to a WebAPI project but am not getting very far.

I have a legacy database which I am looking up some data (its SQL Express 2012 R2). I then populate a local class withe certain properties and return it.

However the JSON serializer is failing when trying to serialize my simple class with this error:

> Error getting value from 'ServerVersion' on 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

This is the class I am serializing. The BaseEntity only has a property on it which is the database context

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id;
    public string Email;
    public int Strikes;
    public Guid AuthenticationKey;

    public User ()
    {
    }
```

And this is the controller

```
public User PutAuthenticate(AuthenticationPayload payload)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState));
        }

        User user;

        try
        {
            user = new User(payload.Email, payload.Password);

            if (user.Strikes >= 3)
            {
                HttpError error = new HttpError("Your account has been locked please contact us to unlock");
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, error));
            }
        }
        catch (CANotFoundException)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }

        return user;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As I often find in writing this I actually managed to solve my own problem. The base class data connection was exposed publically so it was trying to serialize the data context. I just had to change it to be protected